# SWFUpload shows no errors but doesn't upload large video files

Tags: php, file-upload, swfupload

I have an inherited project that is using code igniter, prototype.js and swfUpload to manage large video files. I've run into a problem where it's choking on uploading large video files.

I have uploaded smaller files successfully (~198mb mpg file & 3mb mov file), but am having trouble debugging trouble with uploading a 1.57 GB mov file.

On my local machine the upload completes the upload in ~1 minute, returning as successfuly. But when I go to the uploads folder where the file should exist (and where the smaller files were successfully uploaded) it's missing.

There are no errors in my error log.

In my .htaccess file I'm setting:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 6143M  
php_value post_max_size 6143M
```

I confirmed that this is working by calling ini_get()

This is my SWFUpload object:

```
swfu = new SWFUpload({
   debug: true,
   upload_url: '" . BASE_URL . "/content_management/ajax_asset_upload_files',
   flash_url: '" . BASE_URL . "/js/swfupload/Flash/swfupload.swf',

   post_params: {'PHPSESSID' : '" . $this->session->userdata('session_id') . "'},
   file_size_limit : '10000 MB',
   file_types : '*.*',
   file_types_description : 'All Files',
   file_upload_limit : 100,
   file_queue_limit : 0,
   custom_settings : {
      progressTarget : 'fsUploadProgress'
   },

   // Button settings
   button_image_url: '" . BASE_URL . "/images/buttons/btn_select_file.gif',
   button_width: '105',
   button_window_mode: 'transparent',
   button_height: '20',
   button_placeholder_id: 'spanButtonPlaceHolder',
   button_disabled: true,
   button_cursor: SWFUpload.CURSOR.HAND,
   button_action: SWFUpload.BUTTON_ACTION.SELECT_FILE,

   // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
   file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
   file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
   file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
   upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
   upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
   upload_error_handler : uploadError,
   upload_success_handler : assetUploadSuccess,
   upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
   queue_complete_handler : queueComplete // Queue plugin event
});
```

And the debug output:

```
---SWFUpload Instance Info---
Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
Settings:
   upload_url:               [function location]
   flash_url:                [js_folder]/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1363621116581
   use_query_string:         false
   requeue_on_error:         false
   http_success:             
   assume_success_timeout:   0
   file_post_name:           Filedata
   post_params:              [object Object]
   file_types:               *.*
   file_types_description:   All Files
   file_size_limit:          10000 MB
   file_upload_limit:        100
   file_queue_limit:         0
   debug:                    true
   prevent_swf_caching:      true
   button_placeholder_id:    spanButtonPlaceHolder
   ...
Event Handlers:
   swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
   file_dialog_start_handler assigned: false
   file_queued_handler assigned:       true
   file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
   upload_start_handler assigned:      true
   upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
   upload_error_handler assigned:      true
   upload_success_handler assigned:    true
   upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
   debug_handler assigned:             true

SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             [function location]
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:      
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        10485760000 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      100
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       100
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG:                         PHPSESSID=ki7kne5j6co95il6f6hqt8pje4
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Single Select. Allowed file types: *.*
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
EXCEPTION: 
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: PHPSESSID=ki7kne5j6co95il6f6hqt8pje4
SWF DEBUG: File Post Item: asset_id=131
SWF DEBUG: File Post Item: document_type_id=4
SWF DEBUG: File Post Item: title_id=-1
SWF DEBUG: File Post Item: title=test3
SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for upload.  Starting upload to [upload function] for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 1409024. Total: 1692228612
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 5308416. Total: 1692228612
...
...
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 1692228612. Total: 1692228612
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadSuccess: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0 Response Received: true Data: 
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you really trying to upload a 1.5 gig file witha 0.6 gig upload limit??

Comment: I hope not. Where do you see that upload limit?

Comment: Make sure that `php_value upload_max_filesize` and `php_value post_max_size` are set to maximum file size you want to support/upload.

Comment: oh my mistake... didn't see the last 3

Comment: looks like max_input_time is set to 60 seconds...

Comment: that must be why it stops after exactly 60seconds of upload time with nothing uploaded.

Comment: It was. But I upped max_input_time and max_execution_time to 3000, no change.

Comment: I timed it, my test file 'uploads' in 32 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your host has disabled the ability for you to ini_set php variables like set_time_limit(0) to increase the max execution time, in which case it would use Apache's "Timeout" in httpd.conf, which defaults to 60 seconds.Also set FcgidMaxRequestLen, which is the maximum request length in bytes.

In php, also check: memory_limit

To help you debug, also try:
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Remove any at symbols from your code, too. example: @$varname  or @functionName()
The @ tells PHP to hide any errors that are occurring.

It could be that your error_reporting level is set too low, so there actually is an error, but you're not seeing it. The above should fix that.